# (Java) Access Spring Model without using parameters or ModelAndView

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, parameters, model

Sorry about the title. I couldn't think of a better wording.

Is there any way to set the default Model that Spring will supply the page without first retrieving it as an argument in the @RequestMapping method?

I'm using aspects to take the return value of controller methods(returning the view) and insert it into the model, then rendering a different global view which then includes what I added into the model. This works fine on methods that request the Model as a parameter.

However, I also want to be able to catch all methods that don't explicitly request the model and still insert the return value into it (via @AfterReturning advice). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use the `@Autowired` on `HttpServletRequest` as it will confuse future developers working on the code of threadsafety.

Instead you should use either a `@ModelAttribute` or an `Interceptor`.

#### @ModelAttribute

See:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args

But you can do something like this and add this method to your controller:

```
@ModelAttribute
public preloadModel(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {
    //Add stuff to model.
}
```

#### Interceptor

See: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor

```
public class PreloadModelInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
                       HttpServletResponse response, 
                       Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    // add model attibutes for your view to see but not your controller
    }
}
```

Comment: ModelAttribute works beautifully for what I want. I'll also take a look into the interceptors, but I think this will be good enough for now. Thank you.

Comment: The interceptor is useful if you want to add model attributes to all of your controllers that are needed for you views. For example I typically bind a user object to the model in the interceptor. The `@ModelAttribute` will only apply to the requests that are mapped in the controller that it is in but will be available in the handled request mapping (method with `@RequestMapping`).

Comment: It works for me because I already have a BaseController that all my controllers extend. I'm just setting the necessary vars in the `@ModelAttribute` method there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a workaround. Or maybe it's all that the underlying Spring framework is doing anyway. I just autowired in the HttpServletRequest and called setAttribute. Seems to work fine.